# Scoped metaclasses; or changing class variable of class A during the __init__ of class B containing nested classes inheriting from A?

Tags: python, metaprogramming, metaclass

Consider the code below:

```
class A(object):
    attr = None

    def __init__(self):
        assert A.attr is not None


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, attr):
        A.attr = attr

    class C(A):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()

    class D(A):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()

    nested_classes = {cls.__name__: cls for cls in {C, D}}
```

Above doesn't seem to work as I intend because:

```
>>> first_class = B("first")

>>> first_sub_class = first_class.C()

>>> first_sub_class.attr
'first'

>>> second_class = B("second")

>>> second_sub_class = second_class.C()

>>> second_sub_class.attr
'second'

>>> first_sub_class.attr
'second'
```

Is there a way to have `first_sub_class.attr` be `first` while having `second_sub_class.attr` be `second`? Possibly by having a metaclass whose scope is within B?

A few points:

1. I don't want to pass `attr` around, I want to set it while B is being initialized.
2. I don't want to circumnavigate the point above by using `partial`, since it breaks the rest of the code relying on `__name__` or `__qualname__` or alike.
3. I want to keep faithful to the current structure as much as possible.

Comment: None of these classes is a metaclass.

Comment: No pythonic way. Just pass it around.

Comment: @Aran-Fey None of them are metaclass in a sense that they don't use `__metaclass__`. It's obvious that `C(A)` can't be created if `attr` is not set. Whether you write it with `__metaclass__` or not it won't make a difference for my purpose and I can rewrite the sample if it makes you happy. I'm trying to see whether I can have A not being dynamically scoped, like they are now!

Comment: @MegaIng Don't care what's pythonic or not. As long as I don't have to string interpolation and and an `exec`, I'm fine with a solution.

Comment: In a nutshell, you're only storing the value on `A.attr`. There's only one `A.attr` here which for all intents and purposes acts as a global variable. This is simply not how this works.

Comment: I don't know what you're planning to use this code for, but I *do* know that it shouldn't be done like this. From setting a class attribute in another class's constructor to accessing that class attribute through instances, everything about this code *smells*. I'd recommend taking a step back and asking about your *actual* problem, rather than asking how to fix this code. Nothing good will come from this.

Comment: @deceze Yes. That's reason it doesn't behave like I intend to. Is there a way to have `C` and `D` have an inherited `attr`? Say I define A within __init__ of B, then `C(A)` can't inherit from A, since it doesn't exist yet. I can attach a B.A.__init__ within C.__init__ then, but trying to see if there are other ways.

Comment: The value passed to `B` must obviously be stored in the instance of `B` if you hope that things constructed through `B` should have that value. Start with that. Next, all you really want is to return a new object from a method call on an instance of `B`. Really, what is the difference between `b.C()` being a method and `b.C()` being a "nested class"? Nothing much really. So, something along the lines of: `def C(self): return A(self.value)`…

Comment: @deceze That won't work. `B.C` and `B.D` are completely different, with completely different iteration methods and one `__slots__` etc. Is there a way for B to control how `B.C` and `B.D` are being created?

Comment: @deceze Additionally, setting B.attr and then referencing it within the definition of C and D won't work even though it's not sufficiently different from passing the arg around, because initializing B twice with different values changes B.Cs and B.Ds

Comment: Well then you define a buncha *different* classes and let the methods `B.c()` and `B.d()` return different objects. That happens all the time. E.g. `datetime.datetime.date()` will return a `date` instance from a `datetime` instance, with data specific to that `datetime` instance. You should be taking a closer look at these kinds of examples.

Comment: @deceze Okay. So the method B.c would return an object `C` that's inheriting from `A` whose attributes are dependent on `B`... how's that any different? I mean I could have defined the whole thing with a bunch of nested functions all returning `type(...)` but that's not really the point. The point is how to inherit conditionally, or how to control how classes `B.C` and `B.D` are being created.

Comment: Thinking about that is only useful if you're trying to solve a specific problem. The *behaviour* you want is trivial to implement with some very plain, sane classes (demonstrated below). You'd have to provide some compelling reason for even trying to implement it any other way.

Comment: @deceze As I've said in the other answer, I'm trying to see how far I can bend the language without resorting to either string interpolation and an exec or frame jumping etc. It just feels wrong that such a thing can't be implemented.

Comment: Again: what problem are you trying to solve exactly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem just add the line `self.attr = self.attr` inside the `__init__` function of `A`. Since you don't want to change the attributes of `A`, you will have to make the following changes:

```
class A(object):
    attr = None

    def __init__(self):
        assert self.attr is not None # Don't refer to A, but to self to get the correct value
        self.attr = self.attr


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.attr = attr # Don't edit A, just save the value in own instance

    def __getattribute__(self, item): # completely added, does some magic to ensure class.attr is set correctly 
        if item in B.nested_classes:
            c = B.nested_classes[item]
            c.attr = self.attr
            return c
        return super().__getattribute__(item)

    class C(A):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()

    class D(A):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()

    nested_classes = {cls.__name__: cls for cls in {C, D}}


first_class = B("first")
first_sub_class = first_class.C()
print(first_sub_class.attr)
second_class = B("second")
second_sub_class = second_class.C()
print(second_sub_class.attr)
print(first_sub_class.attr)
```

Comment: That won't work. I don't want `A` to be instantiated at all. But I want to see whether I can have `B.C` and `B.D` being instantiated without passing around the argument. Your solution would have worked if I could have defined `C` and `D` such that they inherit from the A that was modifed but at B.__init__, but that's not possible.

Comment: For this example it works, with only this one line added. At least try it or give an example that doesn't work. Also `A` _is_ instantiated . What do you believe `super().__init__()` does?

Comment: @Megalng This example is the code that I already have, which doesn't behave like I want it! If one does `A()` then one would get an assertion error. If one does `B()` and then `B.C()` and then `A()` then one would not... which is not what I want! Is there a way for B to control how C and D are being created?

Comment: Yes, but that would be complicated and shouldn't be done. _What is your underling problem?_ This question doesn't make sense out of context. In the context you provided, this solution works.

Comment: @Megalng There is no underlying problem. I'm trying to see how far I can bend it without resorting to either frame jumping within C or D or resoring to string interpolation and an exec. If what I want is possible, then how can I do it?

Comment: With the solution I provided. _It works with the context you gave._ If it doesn't fulfill your requirements, give an example where it doesn't work. What I see you writing in the comments fells like total nonsense. Please give examples.

Comment: @Megalng I just did. Both of the codes within my question and the your solution are not desired. What's desired is for a user to be unable to initialize `A()`. If I do `B()` and `B.C()` then `A()` is initializable. Now I can do things like doing a sys.settrace within A and jump back and forth within B, for `A()` to still be uninitializable but I'm trying to see if there's a better way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171355/discussion-between-megaing-and-atonal).

Answer (score 1):

You're insanely overcomplicating this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.attr = attr

class C(A):
    pass

class D(A):
    pass

class B:
    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.attr = attr

    def C(self):
        return C(self.attr)

    def D(self):
        return D(self.attr)
```

Behaves exactly as desired:

```
>>> first_class = B("first")

>>> first_sub_class = first_class.C()

>>> first_sub_class.attr
'first'

>>> second_class = B("second")

>>> second_sub_class = second_class.C()

>>> second_sub_class.attr
'second'

>>> first_sub_class.attr
'first'
```

Comment: That's wrong. `C` and `D` must inherit from `A` and get all of its methods for example. Again, I'm trying to change the class `C` and `D` are inhereting from (not necessarily `B` like they are inhereting from in your solution) within the scope of `B` and that alone.

Comment: @Atonal How are they inheriting from `B`? They inherit from `A` (`C(A)` and `D(A)`)

Comment: `def C(self)` and alike are bad names for functions